# How to iterate a loop every n items with C#

Tags: c#

I have an ObservableCollection and a list of values ​​I want to loop so that I insert 
10 values ​​in turn at a time ObservableCollection and process them. 
I tried

```
Dictionary<string, ObservableCollection<object>> dataDic = new Dictionary<string, ObservableCollection<object>>();
ObservableCollection<ListViewThumbnailViewModel> result;

    foreach (KeyValuePair<string, ObservableCollection<object>> pair in dataDic)
    {
        DateTime _date = DateTime.ParseExact(pair.Key, PRIVATE_DATE_FORMAT, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
        for (int i = 0; i <= dataDic.FirstOrDefault.Value.Count - 1; i += 10)
        {
            result.Insert(i, new ListViewThumbnailViewModel()
            {
                DateItem = _date,
                ListThumbnail = pair.Value
            });
            result.Skip(i).Take(10).ToList();
            Thread.Sleep(100);
        }
    }
 //Show result in screen
_viewModel.ResultSearch.ListResult = new ObservableCollection<ListViewThumbnailViewModel>(result);
```

but it's throw exception : index must be within the bounds of the list. parameter name index

Comment: Can you show how you want the contents of the list to change over time (including what the list initially has) so that we know what you are trying to do?

Comment: Please [edit] post to provide [MCVE]... It is very hard to guess why you see this problem... Especially with lines of code that added just for fun like `result.Skip(i).Take(10).ToList();` which most likely does absolutely nothing...

Comment: I don't think this will compile, but I assumed that the dataDic is a default Dictionary, which FirstOfDefault is a method. The problem you are facing is probably `result.Skip(i)`, the result doesn't have `i` items.

Comment: Are you aware that `result.Skip(i).Take(10).ToList();` is doing _nothing_?

Comment: I updated code, my issue is: 
normally I will add each item of dataDic in turn to the result, but require 10 more items to be displayed then add more.

Answer (score 0):

Your code fails at the insert function: [List insert documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.list-1.insert?view=netframework-4.8)

> **Exceptions**
>
> ArgumentOutOfRangeException
>
> index is less than 0.
>
> **-or-**
>
> index is greater than Count.

You are at the second case. Without having the complete picture of what you are doing, you could modify the code like this:

```
   for (int i = 0; i <= dataDic.FirstOrDefault.Value.Count - 1; i += 10)
    {
        // Protect your code from exception
        if (i <= result.Count) {
            result.Insert(i, new ListViewThumbnailViewModel()
            {
                DateItem = _date,
                ListThumbnail = pair.Value
            });
        }
        result.Skip(i).Take(10).ToList();
        Thread.Sleep(100);
    }
```

Comment: I updated code, my issue is: normally I will add each item of dataDic in turn to the result, but require 10 more items to be displayed then add more. thanks for answer

Answer (score 0):

The problem is you're using the your `i` index but you only check one case, and you don't check it becuase it could break but just because you want to iterate through it.
Here is a solution, with some flaws corrected.

```
Dictionary<string, ObservableCollection<object>> dataDic = new Dictionary<string, ObservableCollection<object>>();
ObservableCollection<ListViewThumbnailViewModel> result = new ObservableCollection<ListViewThumbnailViewModel>();

foreach (KeyValuePair<string, ObservableCollection<object>> pair in dataDic)
{
    DateTime _date = DateTime.ParseExact(pair.Key, PRIVATE_DATE_FORMAT, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
    for (int i = 0; i <= dataDic.FirstOrDefault().Value.Count - 1 && i <= result.Count ; i += 10)
    {
        result.Insert(i, new ListViewThumbnailViewModel()
        {
            DateItem = _date,
            ListThumbnail = pair.Value
        });
        result.Skip(i).Take(10).ToList(); // use the return value here
        Thread.Sleep(100);
    }
}
```

Also be carreful about `firstOrDefault` that first or default can return nothing and it's also a point that can fail.